# ProjectNotFound error when using project ID in GraphQL mutation in Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm working with Apollo Client in a React app and I'm trying to perform a GraphQL mutation to create a new API configuration. The mutation requires a project ID, which I'm supplying correctly via (as far as I can tell). However, I keep encountering a ProjectNotFound error. Here's the relevant code:

```
const CREATE_API_CONFIG = gql`
  mutation CreateApiConfig($projectId: ID!, $input: ApiConfigInput!) {
    createApiConfig(projectId: $projectId, input: $input) {
      id
      project{
        name
      }
      endpoints {
        path
      }
    }
  }
`;

//...

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("projectID :", projectId);

  try {
    const response = await createApiConfig({
      variables: {
        projectId: projectId.toString(),
        input: {
          projectName: apiConfig.projectName,
          endpoints: apiConfig.endpoints,
        },
      },
    });
    console.log(projectId); // Handle the response as needed
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    // Handle the error as needed
  }
};
```

Here is the payload :

```
    {operationName: "CreateApiConfig",…
operationName
: 
"CreateApiConfig"
query
: 
"mutation CreateApiConfig($projectId: ID!, $input: ApiConfigInput!) {\n  createApiConfig(projectId: $projectId, input: $input) {\n    id\n    project {\n      name\n      __typename\n    }\n    endpoints {\n      path\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}"
variables
: 
{projectId: "648a0b8cbbbb4fe73e5702a3", input: {projectName: "codegen2",…}}
input
: 
{projectName: "codegen2",…}
endpoints
: 
[{path: "/tasks/:id", method: "GET", parameters: [{name: "id", type: "String", required: false}],…}]
0
: 
{path: "/tasks/:id", method: "GET", parameters: [{name: "id", type: "String", required: false}],…}
method
: 
"GET"
parameters
: 
[{name: "id", type: "String", required: false}]
0
: 
{name: "id", type: "String", required: false}
name
: 
"id"
required
: 
false
type
: 
"String"
path
: 
"/tasks/:id"
response
: 
[{key: "success", type: "Boolean"}]
0
: 
{key: "success", type: "Boolean"}
key
: 
"success"
type
: 
"Boolean"
projectName
: 
"codegen2"
projectId
: 
"648a0b8cbbbb4fe73e5702a3"}
```

Here is the response :

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Project not found",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 4,
                "column": 5
            }
        ],
        "path": [
            "createApiConfig",
            "project"
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
            "exception": {
                "stacktrace": [
                    "Error: Project not found",
                    "    at Object.getProjectById (C:\\Users\\aradhya\\Desktop\\Ethan Personal Projects\\ai_API\\server\\src\\services\\ProjectService.js:46:15)",
                    "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"data": null
```

}

I've double-checked the project ID to make sure it's correct.
I've checked my ProjectService and the findByiD function works correctly.
I've looked at the Apollo Client documentation and ensured that I'm following the correct syntax for mutations.
I've tested the mutation in the GraphQL playground and Postman and it's working fine there.

Comment: Since you control the server code look at the value of `projectId` at `C:\\Users\\aradhya\\Desktop\\Ethan Personal Projects\\ai_API\\server\\src\\services\\ProjectService.js:46:15` - odds are it's not what you think it should be.